# Python program to extract Combination element available from the data set like Co & Fe available in composition line

Tags: python

This is data set(Sample) which I need to extract the combination available in Composition (Like Co & Fe) only that data set to be extracted

```
{
    "Au": 0.9789814953164448,
    "Az": 2.398972844060257,
    "B prime": 4.016727605471411,
    "B/G": 2.3640597506841443,
    "Bulk modulus": 165.36806388061723,
    "C11": 220.59548272352293,
    "C12": 137.75435445916438,
    "C44": 99.3668085387544,
    "Composition": "Co0.3030303 Fe0.27272727 W0.18181818 Zr0.24242424",
    "Crystal structure": "bcc",
    "EOS": "birchmurnaghan",
    "Formation enthalpy": 0.043437825654109474,
    "Group": "validation set",
    "Lattice constant": 3.1677375834361996,
    "Poisson ratio": 0.31463584118955934,
    "Shear modulus": 69.9508816698735,
    "Total energy": -9166.132333038346,
    "Wigner-Seitz radius": 2.947420065302169,
    "Youngs modulus": 183.91987233205091
},
{
    "Au": 1.8997164025697,
    "Az": 3.2780363186086467,
    "B prime": 4.6337844536189445,
    "B/G": 2.1704056819788873,
    "Bulk modulus": 143.42189861171937,
    "C11": 186.59093474024905,
    "C12": 121.83738054745453,
    "C44": 106.13225120148684,
    "Composition": "Al0.33333333 Co0.16666667 Fe0.16666667 Nb0.33333333",
    "Crystal structure": "bcc",
    "EOS": "birchmurnaghan",
    "Formation enthalpy": 0.00939231493839543,
    "Group": "validation set",
    "Lattice constant": 3.153272722671855,
    "Poisson ratio": 0.30029867452552794,
    "Shear modulus": 66.08068703586932,
    "Total energy": -3599.475639732862,
    "Wigner-Seitz radius": 2.933961241856199,
    "Youngs modulus": 171.8492595289542
},
{
    "Au": 1.93135861191619,
    "Az": 3.30708435057905,
    "B prime": 4.294116013034859,
    "B/G": 1.9451228338196076,
    "Bulk modulus": 147.91852499467285,
    "C11": 197.32920545644592,
    "C12": 123.21318476378632,
    "C44": 122.5539660799438,
    "Composition": "Al0.3030303 Mn0.24242424 Mo0.3030303 Ni0.15151515",
    "Crystal structure": "bcc",
    "EOS": "birchmurnaghan",
    "Formation enthalpy": 0.006908657781423244,
    "Group": "validation set",
    "Lattice constant": 3.071993266900589,
    "Poisson ratio": 0.2805531626159049,
    "Shear modulus": 76.04585295223106,
    "Total energy": -3625.653696273156,
    "Wigner-Seitz radius": 2.8583348073656243,
    "Youngs modulus": 194.7615150036071
},
```

python program to to extract Combination element available from the data set like Co & Fe available in composition line.

Comment: It isn't clear exactly what you are trying to extract. Also -- what code have you written in your attempts to solve the problem? Seeing your code gives us a better idea of what you are trying to do.

Comment: What you are after could be as simple as `[d['Composition'] for d in dict_list]`

Answer (score 1):

First, you will need to get your data as a list of dictionaries. I am not sure how you are loading your data, so I am calling such a list as `list_of_dicts`. If you need help how to do that, I'd suggest you submit a different question. Then it's just a matter of looping through the dictionaries, finding the Composition key and parsing the Elements from the string values. I am showing a solution using regular expression module.

```
import re

list_of_dicts = [{
    "Au": 0.9789814953164448,
    "Az": 2.398972844060257,
    "B prime": 4.016727605471411,
    "B/G": 2.3640597506841443,
    "Bulk modulus": 165.36806388061723,
    "C11": 220.59548272352293,
    "C12": 137.75435445916438,
    "C44": 99.3668085387544,
    "Composition": "Co0.3030303 Fe0.27272727 W0.18181818 Zr0.24242424",
    "Crystal structure": "bcc",
    "EOS": "birchmurnaghan",
    "Formation enthalpy": 0.043437825654109474,
    "Group": "validation set",
    "Lattice constant": 3.1677375834361996,
    "Poisson ratio": 0.31463584118955934,
    "Shear modulus": 69.9508816698735,
    "Total energy": -9166.132333038346,
    "Wigner-Seitz radius": 2.947420065302169,
    "Youngs modulus": 183.91987233205091},
{
    "Au": 1.8997164025697,
    "Az": 3.2780363186086467,
    "B prime": 4.6337844536189445,
    "B/G": 2.1704056819788873,
    "Bulk modulus": 143.42189861171937,
    "C11": 186.59093474024905,
    "C12": 121.83738054745453,
    "C44": 106.13225120148684,
    "Composition": "Al0.33333333 Co0.16666667 Fe0.16666667 Nb0.33333333",
    "Crystal structure": "bcc",
    "EOS": "birchmurnaghan",
    "Formation enthalpy": 0.00939231493839543,
    "Group": "validation set",
    "Lattice constant": 3.153272722671855,
    "Poisson ratio": 0.30029867452552794,
    "Shear modulus": 66.08068703586932,
    "Total energy": -3599.475639732862,
    "Wigner-Seitz radius": 2.933961241856199,
    "Youngs modulus": 171.8492595289542},
{
    "Au": 1.93135861191619,
    "Az": 3.30708435057905,
    "B prime": 4.294116013034859,
    "B/G": 1.9451228338196076,
    "Bulk modulus": 147.91852499467285,
    "C11": 197.32920545644592,
    "C12": 123.21318476378632,
    "C44": 122.5539660799438,
    "Composition": "Al0.3030303 Mn0.24242424 Mo0.3030303 Ni0.15151515",
    "Crystal structure": "bcc",
    "EOS": "birchmurnaghan",
    "Formation enthalpy": 0.006908657781423244,
    "Group": "validation set",
    "Lattice constant": 3.071993266900589,
    "Poisson ratio": 0.2805531626159049,
    "Shear modulus": 76.04585295223106,
    "Total energy": -3625.653696273156,
    "Wigner-Seitz radius": 2.8583348073656243,
    "Youngs modulus": 194.7615150036071}]

for d in list_of_dicts:
    # store the value of the Composition key in composition
    composition = d['Composition'] # is a string
    # split the composition string wherever spaces are present
    composition = composition.split()
    # use regular expressions to substitute digits and period by nothing
    # obtain the composition as a list of elements
    composition = [re.sub(r'\d+|\.', '', i) for i in composition]
    print(composition)
```

Outputs:

```
['Co', 'Fe', 'W', 'Zr']
['Al', 'Co', 'Fe', 'Nb']
['Al', 'Mn', 'Mo', 'Ni']
```

Comment: Actually, there are large number of data like this, I will select the data of on required composition material based on different experimental method,  example I select 'Co' & 'Fe' these material are available at first data set and second data set, then I need to pull all this data. start from "Au" to "Young modulus". there are like 6500 data like this. i need to run experiment on different combination.